# Trying to understand how bundle.js executes using Webpack

Tags: javascript, module, webpack, webpack-2

while looking at the bundle.js, producted from webpack, i can see "webpackBootstrap" function wrapped inside parenthesis. Since it is not IIFE, "webpackBootstrap" function inside it seems to be running magically.

Seems other function, again wrapped inside parenthesis has array of modules which some how is feeding into first function but am vague on how it is executing. Thus seeking help to understand execution flow of "bundle.js".

```
    /******/ (function(modules) { // webpackBootstrap
/******/    // The module cache
/******/    var installedModules = {};
/******/
/******/    // The require function
/******/    function __webpack_require__(moduleId) {
/******/
/******/        // Check if module is in cache
/******/        if(installedModules[moduleId]) {
/******/            return installedModules[moduleId].exports;
/******/        }
/******/        // Create a new module (and put it into the cache)
/******/        var module = installedModules[moduleId] = {
/******/            i: moduleId,
/******/            l: false,
/******/            exports: {}
/******/        };
/******/
/******/        // Execute the module function
/******/        modules[moduleId].call(module.exports, module, module.exports, __webpack_require__);
/******/
/******/        // Flag the module as loaded
/******/        module.l = true;
/******/
/******/        // Return the exports of the module
/******/        return module.exports;
/******/    }
/******/
/******/
/******/    // expose the modules object (__webpack_modules__)
/******/    __webpack_require__.m = modules;
/******/
/******/    // expose the module cache
/******/    __webpack_require__.c = installedModules;
/******/
/******/    // identity function for calling harmony imports with the correct context
/******/    __webpack_require__.i = function(value) { return value; };
/******/
/******/    // define getter function for harmony exports
/******/    __webpack_require__.d = function(exports, name, getter) {
/******/        if(!__webpack_require__.o(exports, name)) {
/******/            Object.defineProperty(exports, name, {
/******/                configurable: false,
/******/                enumerable: true,
/******/                get: getter
/******/            });
/******/        }
/******/    };
/******/
/******/    // getDefaultExport function for compatibility with non-harmony modules
/******/    __webpack_require__.n = function(module) {
/******/        var getter = module && module.__esModule ?
/******/            function getDefault() { return module['default']; } :
/******/            function getModuleExports() { return module; };
/******/        __webpack_require__.d(getter, 'a', getter);
/******/        return getter;
/******/    };
/******/
/******/    // Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call
/******/    __webpack_require__.o = function(object, property) { return Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(object, property); };
/******/
/******/    // __webpack_public_path__
/******/    __webpack_require__.p = "";
/******/
/******/    // Load entry module and return exports
/******/    return __webpack_require__(__webpack_require__.s = 0);
/******/ })
/************************************************************************/
/******/ ([
/* 0 */
/***/ (function(module, exports) {



function hello(){
    console.log('hello world');
}


hello();


/***/ })
/******/ ]);
```

Comment: Why do you say it is not IIFE? Try putting `(function(a) { console.log(a); })(['1', '2', '3']);` into your browser console and see that it works - it's not magic.

Comment: It actually is an IIFE, the function is called with an array of functions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Webpack does indeed wrap everything in an IIFE, and that function runs in the following steps:

1. `webpack` wraps everything in an IIFE, which gets invoked with all the modules (as an array)
2. `webpack` creates a `__webpack_require__` function, which internally requires modules when needed
3. `webpack` kicks off by running the first module (which is the entry module) using the `__webpack_require__` function
4. all previous require statements get replaced with an invocation of `__webpack_require__` with the correct module index from the passed in array

The above 4 points are from a blog post I wrote, and [you're free to check it out here for more information.](https://callmenick.com/dev/cooking-with-webpack-1-introduction/)

Comment: as per my understanding once webpack outputs "bundle.js" file webpack job is done. then we link bundle.js in html page. So, looking at code in bundle.js solely there does not seem to be IIFE. So i am wondering how  (function(modules) { // webpackBootstrap... is getting executed on first place.

Comment: The code inside the compiled bundle.js file is an IIFE: `(function(modules) {})([function() {}, function() {}])`

Comment: I was missing IIFE with all that code, when you told it was IIFE i realized then that array was passed as argument. Thanks, appreciate.